# WPF TabItem Name of Open File

Tags: c#, wpf, tabitem

I've built a little editor in WPF/C# and am trying to figure out how to display the open filename (not path) as the TabItem2 header. Can someone please assist? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tabItem.Header = new System.IO.FileInfo(filepath).Name;
```

or some variations of this, depending on what exactly do you have.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So I would add this line to my open file dialog and save file dialog code or? Sorry I'm new to C#/WPF...

Comment: Mainly yes, after those dialogs are closed successfully (not canceled), you could add this line, provided that tabItem is the TabItem control in which you display the file.

Comment: Ahhh, this works great for save dialog and open dialog, but not doesn't change the name when selecting File -> New. Here is my code:

private void ProcessNewCommand()
        {
            if (dataChanged)
            {
                string sf = SaveFirst();
                if (sf != "Cancel")
                {
                    ClearState();                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ClearState();
            }
        }

Comment: You didn't said anything about New. But i guess it's sufficient to add `tabItem.Header = "untitled"` where you do ClearState (which I assume id empties your editor) - but I'm pretty sure you can handle new similar to Save and Open ;)